# Flutter failed to compile apk: Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, apk, build.gradle

Flutter failed to compile an apk. I am not sure if this has something to do with AndroidX or something.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I ran `flutter clean`. I also ran `flutter run -v`. This is what happened: https://1drv.ms/t/s!An3OLJ7n0CjEku1SBrSABWab901z3Q

(I have used an external file locker because the stack trace is too large for the Stack Overflow editor).

This issue is similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30634

Comment: Yes you have to upgrade to AndroidX

Comment: Use this link to do so: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: But there are some things in this link that are outdated. Make sure after you follow the instructions in the link, check if you still have errors in your files (the ones that you had to modify in the link )

Comment: Experiencing a similar issue I've googled and found this page. Changing Gradle versions and other suggestions here haven't helped. But I recently added Firebase and Crashlytics to my app and removing those at least meant my apk built. Ergo the problem seems to lay there i.m.o.

Answer (score 6):

try follow steps:
1. in gradle-wrapper.properties, downgrade from **5.1.1 to 4.10.2.**
2. int root/build.gradle, change android gradle version into **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'**
Hope it is useful

Answer (score 3):

It is common after migration to androidX. 
If you followed recommended route from here: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

**Try this:**

Check with steps in "not recommended" way in above tutorial if every listed files is same as in your project, especially :

- in `root/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip` (probably you have version 5.1.1 )
- in `root/android/build.gradle`, set 
  `dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
  }`
- check if in `root/android/app/build.gradle` SDK version is set to minimum 28 for: 
  `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`

**If you still get error then here is what helped me:**

- delete .gradle and .m2 folders from `$HOME` directory, as well with in app folders: `root/android/.gradle` and `root/build`
- `flutter doctor`
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter packages pub cache clean`
- if you changed (as me) app icon then run:
  `flutter packages pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`
  it will render icons for app - without it print same error with gradle..
- Invalidate caches in Android Studio `"File" > "Invalidate Caches / Restart..."`

**If nothing from above works open android project as module**

(*you can do it by opening any file inside android folder for example manifest, then bar above code will shows with link to "Open for Editing in Android Studio", more here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio* )

Then click on gradle tab on the left and compile app - should show now more detailed error message.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is your fix, open android sdk settings and uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages and in sdk tools, Check Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) than click ok/apply. It will download old SDK. Than Restart the IDE, Run default flutter program on emulator. This error occurs because flutter isn't compatible with latest Android SDK so you have yo manually install old SDK in Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try running "flutter clean" in the project. If it doesn't work, please paste the output after running "flutter run -v".

Comment: Here is what happened when i ran "flutter run -v" https://1drv.ms/t/s!An3OLJ7n0CjEku1SBrSABWab901z3Q

Comment: This still seems to be a migration to AndroidX error. Can you check if your build.grade is compatible with AndroidX and gradle.properties is set according to this guide: [Migrating to AndroidX] (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

In the debug mode applications worked well, but when I tried to build a release version, it had this error.

1. "Flutter doctor -v" was ok.
2. Made flutter clean.
3. Checked all AndroidX recommendations, used all latest versions of packages.
4. Checked android/app/fourpillarsappru1.keystore settings.

Finally the decision was use build in in Android Studio commands instead of command line "flutter build apk".

So, the decision in my case was:

1. Open build.gradle for editing in Android Studio

[image]

2. Choose Build / Generate Signed Bundle/APK

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solve the error by running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all licenses agreement.

I hope it will help

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by running flutter doctor. This is the error message that showed up:
 '✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses' 

I was able to quickly follow the instructions from the message and got my app running on the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution that works for me and makes the most sense CLEAN CACHE

Enter Command below

```
--> flutter packages pub cache clean
```

Comment: This command does not even work. What works for you and in what case?

Comment: In the case where you have followed all the instructions in the Android X migration (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) and want to see the change effected

What does it say when you enter the command?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the build gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` from `5.1.1` to `4.10.2` worked for me.
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

**Dependencies in project: build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
 }
```

**module: build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def versionPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("../version.properties")
def versionProperties = new Properties()
versionProperties.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropertiesFile))
def flutterVersionCode = versionProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
def flutterVersionName = versionProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lok.sewa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your key.properties file. There might be error in key path, keyAlias or passwords. The error by key errors is not traceable. 
This solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It is android problems only so
Open in Android Studio
and pick Flutter->Open module in Android Studio
menu Build->Build Bundle(s) / APKs->Build Bundles.

Answer (score 0):

My code contain keystore info in build.gradle,but we don't have keystore file in our git repository.My colleague uploaded his local keystore file and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just simply fixed it by changing the minSdkVersion . Just try minSdkVersion 19 or 21. It will fix. 
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29